# IE Edge/11 : Weird cursor behavior for form fields

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am facing a weird behavior of cursor in form fields, is there any way to fix it with css or something else?

I am using bootstrap, following is my code and preview for cursor. Sometimes it show up like figure A and sometime like figure B.

[image]

```
<form>
    <label for="inputEmail">Username</label>
    <input name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input name="inputPassword" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/strange-cursor-appearance-in-text-box/2bbc4b87-9d74-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?page=2&auth=1) In IE goto Internet Options > Advanced > and check the option "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering*"

This will resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your problem. This CodePen is illustrating that.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwOYxB

```
<form>
    <label for="inputEmail">Username</label>
    <input name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input name="inputPassword" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password">
</form>
```

Are you using other css to override Bootstrap style?

Comment: Apparently there are other people complaining about some weird behavior in IE11 and Edge.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/strange-cursor-appearance-in-text-box/2bbc4b87-9d74-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1